# Application of the Fourier transform properties

Tags: fourier-transform

Here is an exercise about the properties of the Fourier transform.

Given $f(x)=\frac{e^{ -x^2}}{\sqrt{ \pi}} $ and $g(x)=xe^{ -2x^2}$, and knowing that the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is $\hat{f}(k)=e^{ -k^2/4}$, how can I evaluate the Fourier transform $\hat{g}(k)$ of $g(x)$ exploiting the properties of the Fourier transform?

I came to see that $g(x)=x\sqrt{\pi}f(x\sqrt{2})$ but I cannot see how to go on from that as I would have to combine more than just one property of the FT.

The expected result is $\hat{f}(k)=i \sqrt{\pi} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{-k^2/8}\right)$.

Thank you in advance for the help and merry Christmas anybody!

Comment: You need two properties. (we assume the mathematics convention for the Fourier transform)
$$\mathcal F(x\mapsto f(\lambda x))(\xi)=\frac{1}{|\lambda |}\mathcal F(f)(\xi/\lambda)$$
For $\lambda \in\Bbb R$ and
$$\mathcal F(x^n\mapsto xf(x))(\xi)=\frac{\mathrm i^n}{(2\pi)^n}(\mathrm D\mathcal F)(f)(\xi)$$
Where $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier transform operator and $\mathrm D$ is the derivative operator.

Comment: I really think people should stop to exercise their arrogance by voting to close questions. She perfectly described the problem, she wrote some attempt and she also used MathJax. Show some respect and be kind instead.

Comment: Thank you!! This helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

I am suspicious about the "expected result".

We proceed by forst of all observing the function can be Fourier-Transformed for it is absolutely integrable, Lebesgue-measurable on the real line, indeed:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert x e^{-2x^2}\vert \text{d}x = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Then proceed by calling the function $h_k(x) \equiv e^{-2kx^2}$, such that

$$g(x) \equiv -\dfrac{1}{4} \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} h_k(x)\bigg|_{k = 1}$$

Now, let's recall the property of the Fourier Transform of a derivative:

$$\mathcal{F}\left(\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} f(x), s\right) = - i s \mathcal{F}(f(x), s)$$

which in this case reads

$$\mathcal{F}\left(-\dfrac{1}{4} \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} h_k(x)\bigg|_{k = 1}\right) = -\dfrac{1}{4} (- i s) \mathcal{F}\left(e^{-2kx^2}\right)\bigg|_{k = 1} = \dfrac{1}{8} i s \frac{e^{-\frac{s^2}{8 k}}}{2 \sqrt{k}}\bigg|_{k = 1} = \dfrac{1}{8} i s\ e^{-s^2/8}$$

There are different conventions which may or may not introduce additional $2\pi$ factors, though. Sometimes it's a $\sqrt{2\pi}$ factor, this depends on how you defined F.T.

Merry Christmas Ilaria!